# How do I create several concentric buffers in a loop in R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, buffer, loop

I am working with polygons and I need to create concentric buffers every ten kilometers until I reach a distance of 70 kilometers, in this sense I want only the 10 kilometers rings without the polygon that generated the buffer.

I want something like this:
[image]
I wanted to do a loop, because I have to do it for several shapefiles or a lapply.

I have eight minas sahpes and for each of them I will have to make the seven buffers (from ten to 70 kilometers)

this code works but would like to do a loop:

```
library(raster)    
library(rgeos)    
library(rgdal)    


buff_min10km<- gBuffer(minas, width=10000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min20km<- gBuffer(minas, width=20000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min30km<- gBuffer(minas, width=30000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min40km<- gBuffer(minas, width=40000, byid = TRUE)   
buff_min40km<- gBuffer(minas, width=40000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min50km<- gBuffer(minas, width=50000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min60km<- gBuffer(minas, width=60000, byid = TRUE)
buff_min70km<- gBuffer(minas, width=70000, byid = TRUE)
```

After taht I take out the center:

```
ring10km<- gDifference(buff_min10km, minas)    
ring20km <- gDifference(buff_min20km, buff_min10km, byid = TRUE)    
ring30km <- gDifference(buff_min30km, buff_min20km, byid = TRUE)    
ring40km <- gDifference(buff_min40km, buff_min30km, byid = TRUE)    
ring50km <- gDifference(buff_min50km, buff_min40km, byid = TRUE)
ring60km <- gDifference(buff_min60km, buff_min50km, byid = TRUE)
ring70km <- gDifference(buff_min70km, buff_min60km, byid = TRUE)
```

I tired this but didnt work :

```
bufferring<-seq(10000, 70000, by=10000)

outerBuffer<-function(x, dist){
 buff<-gBuffer(x, width = dist - 1, byid = T)
 e<-erase(buff,x)
 return(e)
 }

for (l in 1:length(bufferring) ){
ring<-outerBuffer(minas,bufferring)
}
```

Give me this error:

```
Error in gBuffer(x, width = dist - 1, byid = T) : 
length(width) == n is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide *minas* so I do not really know if this code will work as you wish. In any case, you can try something like the following:

First, create your names. You can do it either like that:

```
buff_labs <- paste0("buff_min", seq(10,70, by=10),"km")
```

Or using magrittr's forward pipes:

```
library(magrittr)
buff_labs <- seq(10,70, by=10) %>% paste0("buff_min", .,"km")
```

Then, create your buffering:

```
buffering<-seq(10000, 70000, by=10000)
names(buffering) <- buff_labs
```

Use `mapply()` to loop:

```
buffers <- mapply(FUN = rgeos::gBuffer,
                 width = buffering,
                 MoreArgs = list(spgeom =minas, byid=TRUE),
                 SIMPLIFY = FALSE, 
                 USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Then make a list with your centers:

```
centers <- c(minas, buffers[1:(length(buffers)-1)])
```

And calculate the rings:

```
rings <-mapply(FUN = rgeos::gDifference,
             spgeom1 = buffers,
             spgeom2 = centers,
             SIMPLIFY = FALSE, 
             USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

You got yourself all your buffers in a nice list in which each element is accessible by name and position. To plot them you just have to loop along the list.

Hope it helps

**ADDENDUM**

If you want to save them we can use, for example, the function `rgdal::writeOGR()`. To be able to use this function, objects must be SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. Thus, we proceed as follows:

First, we create as many data.frames as buffers. Here I'm using the labels we gave to the buffer to create a data.frame per label:

```
data.aux <- lapply(buff_labs, as.data.frame, col.names = "buffer")
```

Then we use `sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame()` function to link *SpatialPolygons* and *dataframes* looping everything with `mapply()`

```
rings.spdf <- mapply(sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame,
                     Sr=rings,
                     data=data.aux)
```

Last, we save each buffer as *ESRI shapefile* in the HDD using:

```
mapply(FUN = rgdal::writeOGR,
       obj=rings.spdf,
       dsn = paste0("PathToYourFolder", buff_labs, ".shp"),
       layer = buff_labs,
       MoreArgs = list(
         driver = "ESRI Shapefile",
         encoding = "utf8",
         overwrite_layer = TRUE),
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE, 
       USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

Note that *encoding* is set as UTF8 and *overwrite* as TRUE. Check out that the value of those parameters is really compatible with what you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank you.                                                                                                                                               It worked, but I need to save it in my directory as a shapefile `(SpatialPolygonDataFrame)` , because I'll use them to extract pixels values from a raster.                                                                                                                                           I would like to share my data here, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If hepls here is a link with my data:                                                                                          https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BzITbGX9gmxz4FEuTT5q-ayUjI559uF1

Comment: Do not worry. I'll edit my answer so you can save them as ESRI shapefiles

Comment: thank you very much!!!!
it worked very well ....
You saved me hours of work.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! :)

Comment: Sorry, one more doubt. When I used the `rgeos::gDifference`, the features of the input minas fade out, there are any way of I get back. Acttualy , tried to replace the `rgeos:: gDifference`, by `raster::erase`, because this function preserv the input features. but, turned this error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘erase’ for signature ‘"missing", "missing"’`

Comment: To test the functions I used the following "_minas_": `minas <- readWKT("POLYGON((0 1,0.95 0.31,0.59 -0.81,-0.59 -0.81,-0.95 0.31,0 1))")`. If I use `raster::erase` as follows: `rings <-mapply(FUN = raster::erase, x = buffers, y = centers, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)` the function works. I tried to download your data but it seems I need some special authorization to access it, so I cannot test anything further. Another option you may have is to save the attributes of _minas_ in a data.frame and incorporate them when you build `rings.spdf`

Comment: The erase function works, but when I try to build the `rings.spf` I had this error:               `Error in (function (Sr, data, match.ID = TRUE)  : Object length mismatch:
     dots[[1L]][[1L]] has 7 Polygons objects, but dots[[2L]][[1L]] has 1 rows`

Comment: Are you sure you have as many rows in your data frames as polygons in your buffers/rings? I sent you a request to get your data

Comment: Yes. i gave you permison now.

Comment: @KledsonLemes I sent you an email with follow up questions. Just so you know in case it went to your SPAM